# Blackberry Device Movement Angle Difference

Tags: blackberry, accelerometer

I am working on a Blackberry application in which I need to retrieve the Angle difference when the device moves. It means the difference of angle between when the movement starts and ends. It must be 25 degrees to call some function.

In simple words, call a function when the device moves by 25 degrees.

Comment: please help me in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [AccelerometerSensor docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerSensor.html), it is available in API 4.7.0 and higher. All data that you can retrieve is described in class [AccelerometerData](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerData.html), it is orientation and acceleration (gravity data).

It is described more in details how to get angle from gravity sensor data in [JavaME docs, "Mobile Sensor API" section](http://java.sun.com/javame/overview/techpapers/index.jsp):

> If the phone was placed flat, the accelerometer would tell us that the acceleration along the z-axis (up and down) is about 1000 (this value represents 1G). The accelerations along the X and Y axises (sideways) would be about 0 since the phone is sitting still and gravity only works downwards. Flipping the phone over with the screen facing down, the accelerometer would give us the value of -1000 on the Z-axis. Standing on its side, would give us a value of 1000 or -1000 along either the X- or the Y-axis, depending on which side you put it. Putting the phone in a 45 degree angle along the X-axis would give us a value of Â±707 on the Z-axis and Â±707 on the Y-axis, since gravity cannot affect either axis with its full force (You can easily calculate what the value should be for a certain angle for each axis using the sine and cosine functions). Using the values from the X and Y-axis from the accelerometer, we can determine the position of the phone at any time, and then use that value to move our ship to avoid the incoming asteroids.

So, having accelerometer data for all 3 axes we may figure it out what is horizontal angle of a device.